# ZX Spin emulator, built-in assembly errors

Tags: emulation, assembly, sinclair, zxspectrum

I'm having problems understanding how to get an assembly file to run 
inside the [ZX Spin](http://www.zophar.net/sinclair/zx-spin.html) emulator using the built-in assembler. I'm able to assemble my program but it seems to crash each time I attempt to run the assembled object code.

I cannot find any documentation on how this is meant to be set to run.

The message I get with version is v0.7:

> Access violation at address 0060470C in module 'ZXSpin.exe'. Write of address 05603622"

Any help on getting this working with the most simple of assembly files would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that version 0.7 had a bug in the assembler as that part was no longer being maintained and subsequently had been broken between releases.

I tried the previous version and it worked correctly (so I made a wonderful dot). Thanks to anyone who helped out with this. Can't recall the forum where I was provided with that info, but thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I had that error too with both 0.7 and 0.66 version, but I've found a solution.
Get to Tools/Options/System and change "When no longer active application" to "Keep running with sound"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 0.666.  Try to set a conditional breakpoint.